# Live HTML5 grayscale

Tags: jquery, ajax, live

I need to use this script for a website gallery: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover/

This works great for images already loaded:

```
   $(window).load(function(){
                $('.item img').each(function(){
        this.src = grayscale(this.src);
        });
    });
function grayscale(src){ //blabla };
```

**The problem is that I load next images with ajax, and the effect is not applied to new ajax elements.**

Thank you!

***If I load my function on success, the effect will overwrite the existent grayed images!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call that method on success callback of the AJAX:

```
function foo(){
    $('.item img').each(function(){
    this.src = grayscale(this.src);
    });
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: foo,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: This will overwrite the existent gray images, or if I leave this only on success will leave the elements first loaded without the effect. :) I also load new images with https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Comment: @FlorescuAdrian. So in the success only update those images that currently loaded...

Comment: How can I do that? I guess I need to add a class to the new items, but I add new images on scroll. Hm... Thank you for you time! I think I will try to find a new solution to gray my images. :)